# Why Custom Catalog URL Rewrites deleted after reindex?

Tags: magento, url-rewriting, magento-1.7

I am using magento 1.7 version.When I create custom rewrite rules from back-end then they work fine but when I do re-indexing then all rewrite rules deleted.

Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: I am having the same issue.  Did you ever ind a solution to the problem?>

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have missed Redirect to `Permanent (301)`

Edit custom URL Rewrite and Set Redirect to `Permanent (301)`

If it does not help then follow this [tutorial](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/adding-page-links-in-the-navigation-bar)

Comment: I already did this.It is working fine normally but when I do re-indexing then It is not working